# Represent the continuous function with base

Tags: matrices, functions, vectors

I need to prove that any function can be represented with base $$\{1,x,x^2,...,x^n,...\}$$

---

I've proved that this set of function is linear independent with help of Wronskian. Is this enough to say that any function can be represented with base(set) of this function? Or there are some more demands?

Comment: The claim is (far too vague and) not true.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli oops. i corrected the base. It should be true now, right?

Comment: Only polynomials could be represented with that base.  Even if you allowed infinite sums, which is not standard, you could only represent analytic functions which are not all continuous functions 9(by far).

Comment: @НиколайЖурба It is true that you may want to add constants, but it's the least of the problems.

Comment: Although the statement in question is false (even for continuous functions), it seems to me to be close to Weierstrass approximation theorem, which could be instructive for the OP.

Comment: @badjohn could you give an example of continuous function that is not analytic?

Comment: John Doe did that already.

Comment: @Николай Журба Any non-differentiable function works as an example. Since analytic functions are differentiable infinitely many times, even differentiable functions are not analytic (I work in $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ setting). For instance, $x^n_+$ works for any positive intreger $n$. Namely, such a function is $n-1$ times differentiable, but not $n$ times. In $\Bbb C$ setting, if a function has a derivative, it is analytic, in particular, it is infinitely many times differentiable. So, here the situation is completely different.

Comment: @amsmath and if write abs(x) as system: abs(x)=x, x>=0, abs(x)=-x, x<0. Does it count that we represented the function with given base?

Comment: John Doe gave you an example. Here's another $f(x) = 0$ if $x \le 0$ otherwise $x$.

Comment: @badjohn See my comment, please. :)

Comment: I accidentally deleted my comment, and can see that some people referenced it - my example was $|x|$.

Comment: @szw I see it.  I assumed that the OP was working with the reals. If we want a complex counterexample then the conjugate function is a simple one.

Comment: This is impossible to answer unless you clarify the actual meaning of "*can be represented*". I would dare to say that $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ cannot be represented in terms of monomials since it has a too rapid growth on the positive real axis. On the other hand, the Weierstrass approximation theorem states that any continuous function over a compact interval can be uniformly approximated by a sequence of polynomials; the Bernstein-Jackson theorem relates the magnitude of the error with the regularity of the given function and we have much more (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MuentzsTheorem.html).

Comment: I would also say that if $g$ belongs to the closure of $\text{span}(1,x,x^2,\ldots)$ then the Laplace transform of $g$ is holomorphic over $\text{Re}(s)>0$. So the super-smooth function $e^s\sin(s)$ does not belong to such space, since its Laplace transform has two simple poles at $s=1\pm i$.